# 500 Internal Server Error instead of 404 Page Not Found

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

Any idea why I get internal server errors instead of 404 errors?

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

That's whats in my .htaccess file, so I really don't know why it does that... :/

Also note, this is on a subdomain... On the main domain it works fine, but on subdomains the htaccess file never works...

Comment: Do you have other .htaccess directives to prettify urls or otherwise change your routing scheme?

Comment: What happens when you point your browser to example.com/404.shtml

Comment: stark: If I point my browser to the 404 file it works fine. 
Andrew: I don't have anything else in my htaccess file, thats the only line in it right now.

Comment: Type some random url and see what it throws?

Comment: Starx: 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: what does the apache error log contain?

Comment: @Jonny When you're responding to someone in a comment, start it with '@' and their name, that tells SO to notify them.

Comment: check if `htaccess` is enabled in the virtual host configuration for your subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

Is the file `404.html` **exists?**

In some servers you could find something like *"404 file not found ... Additionally, the 404 page was not found"*.

If it is a subdomain, maybe the file `404.html` does not exist as well, or the server could not find it because of configuration mistakes.

Comment: 404.html exists in the folder :/